# 202 Accepted while accessing wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

I've written a WCF service, which works fine in Visual Studio running locally.

However, when I install the service on a server running IIS 8.5 and try calling it (using the same code, with only the URL changed and uses https), the service returns 202 Accepted rather than the expected response.

I tried googling it but could not find anything.
Can somebody please help me out.
[Web.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBDV1.png)

[WCf Method call from angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7sfq.png)

[Response data from WCF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoG21.png)

Comment: would you mind sharing your example more details wish me? I think the problem maybe caused by the service configuration.

Comment: Yeah i have a WCF service.. A development server and a production server and production site runs as https. The service gets data from an external database. In the development server i have Visual studio and i publish/deploy directly but for the production server i just deploy the wsp. I get proper data in my development site but not in production. In production, it says 202 Accepted

Comment: Hi @AbrahamQian Could you please suggest a way to resolve the issue.

Comment: show me your project, I try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I don't think i can share the project. Is it enough if i share the config file?

Comment: Updated your question.